# Determine what file a syntax error coming from

Tags: python, django, syntax-error

I am having an incredibly frustrating time trying to get off the ground with a Django setup.  I'm sure it has something to do with a no-no regarding python3 and something in my requirements file.  Anyways when I run this command from my Django project directory:

```
python3 manage.py runserver --settings=my_test_app.settings.development
```

the only output I get is

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (__init__.py, line 6)
```

I can't, for the life of me, figure out what `__init__.py` file this error message is talking about.  I've tried to set a breakpoint with pdb, tried to catch an Exception around the calling code, and even put print statements in all of the `__init__` files in my project but no dice.  Does anybody have an idea of what might be going on here? Or at least how to figure out what file is causing this syntax error?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: it could possibly be init.py of your settings module.

Comment: If you are using python 3.x then you should have to install django 1.5. Might it could resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'm rocking Django 1.5 via pip and virtualenv so should be good there. Also, my setting module __init__.py is empty; does not even have a line 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem when:

- starting from django-twoscoops-project template

  django-admin.py startproject --template=https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-        project/archive/master.zip --extension=py,rst,html project_name app_name
- with django-debug-toolbar ver 0.9.4

Disabling django-debug-toolbar or upgrading django-debug-toolbar in requirements.txt to 1.0.1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the Python documentation:

> Instances of this class have attributes filename, lineno, offset and
>   text for easier access to the details. str() of the exception instance
>   returns only the message.

So maybe the Exception's filename attribute has a longer path? If not, it would have to be an `__init__.py` that's directly on one of your `PYTHONPATH` paths.